# Opencv python LineIterator returning position information?

Tags: ros, python, opencv, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the python sample for InitLineIterator [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_drawing_functions.html?highlight=lineiterator#InitLineIterator):
Copied below for convenience:

```
>>> import cv
>>> img = cv.LoadImageM("building.jpg", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
>>> li = cv.InitLineIterator(img, (100, 100), (125, 150))
>>> red_sum = 0
>>> green_sum = 0
>>> blue_sum = 0
>>> for (r, g, b) in li:
...     red_sum += r
...     green_sum += g
...     blue_sum += b
>>> print red_sum, green_sum, blue_sum
10935.0 9496.0 7946.0
```

Is there a way to also get the pixel positon?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10160/opencv-python-lineiterator-returning-position-information?/) by [Marrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/238/marrok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2011-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I couldn't find an existing one, so I reimplemented the algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm); but I still feel like the built-in line iterator should return position information.

```
def bresenham_march(img, p1, p2):
   x1 = p1[0]
   y1 = p1[1]
   x2 = p2[0]
   y2 = p2[1]
   steep = math.fabs(y2 - y1) > math.fabs(x2 - x1)
   if steep:
      t = x1
      x1 = y1
      y1 = t

      t = x2
      x2 = y2
      y2 = t
   also_steep = x1 > x2
   if also_steep:
      
      t = x1
      x1 = x2
      x2 = t

      t = y1
      y1 = y2
      y2 = t

   dx = x2 - x1
   dy = math.fabs(y2 - y1)
   error = 0.0
   delta_error = 0.0; # Default if dx is zero
   if dx != 0:
       delta_error = math.fabs(dy/dx)

   if y1 = 0.5:
         y += y_step
         error -= 1

   if also_steep:
       ret.reverse()

   return ret
```

---

Originally posted by [Marrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/238/marrok/) with karma: 38 on 2011-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1